# Shibboleth Errors When Authenticating Through a Reverse Proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, saml, shibboleth

I am attempting to configure a new Shibboleth based SP that will authenticate via my SAML iDP (Duo Access Gateway).

My Shibboleth SP is running behind an IIS-based reverse proxy that rewrites the URL's to the SP. The SP and Shibboleth itself are running on Apache on a Windows Server.

The issue with this configuration is that my SP (Shibboleth) believes it's running on, let's call it "sp.mycompany.com". However my iDP is delivering the assertion to the reverse proxy address "proxy.mycompany.com" which then rewrites the request to "sp.mycompany.com". This results in Sibboleth throwing the error "SAML message delivered with POST to incorrect server URL" to the user, and logging an error of "POST targeted at (https://proxy.mycompany.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST), but delivered to (http://sp.mycompany.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST)" in the Shibd log.

I've been searching but have only found fixes for this that apply to different situations than mine.

EDIT: Reverse Proxy Config Added Below

```
`<configuration>
    <system.webS<rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Duo" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match filterByTags="None" pattern="^Shibboleth.sso/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="https://proxy.mycompany.com/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" enabled="true">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://sp.mycompany.com/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://proxy.mycompany.com/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Duo" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^dag/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://duo.mycompany.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://sp.mycompany.com/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <rewriteMaps>
                <rewriteMap name="test" />
            </rewriteMaps>
        </rewrite>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="https://proxy.mycompany.com/dag" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>`
```

Comment: Can you share your configuration of proxy and reverse proxy?

Comment: @Akshay added reverse proxy config in original post

Comment: I had the same problem, but with a Apache based reverse proxy. I fixed it by specifying the ServerName with https:// scheme. See if IIS has a similar setting. This ServerName is used in redirects.